# Issue with Image Alignment - Images Not Aligning Properly

Tags: html

I'm currently working on an HTML project and facing an issue with image alignment. Despite setting up my images within a container, they don't seem to align properly. Here's a simplified version of my code:

```css
.image-container {
  display: flex;
}

.image-container img {
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="image-container">
  <img src="image1.jpg" alt="Image 1">
  <img src="image2.jpg" alt="Image 2">
  <img src="image3.jpg" alt="Image 3">
</div>
```

Comment: Please update the snippet I made you with actual images from for example lorem pixel and explanation of what you expect

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by images not aligning properly. Can you post a screenshot showing the image alignment issue ?

Comment: We also have no idea what size your images are. Reiterating the call for reproducing a working example here please.